# Cannot add Autorization header to my requests with guzzle services

Tags: php, guzzle

I have following code:

```
Client class


    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient;
    use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\Description;

     class ApiClient extends Client
     {
       public static function factory($config = array())
       {
        $config = array_merge($config, json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/Resources/config/client.json'), TRUE));

        $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(new Client(), new Description($config));

        return $guzzleClient;
    }
}
```

Config settings

```
   {
    "operations": {
        "me":{
            "description": "Returns user profile details",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "uri": "users/me",
            "parameters": {
                "token": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "location": "header",
                    "sentAs": "Authorization"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```

Usage

```
$config = [
    'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/api/v1/'
];
$api_client = ApiClient::factory($config);

$token   = 'Bearer V6tBMG6FKL7wLxZh116IGdvfDUtOvlFIJI61nrHp';
$command = $api_client->me(array(
    'token' => $token
));

// returns an array of results
$results = $command->execute();
```

And I want add custom Autorizarion Bearer header to all requests, how I can do that? Add header to $client doesn't help cuz $command after call me method is NULL.

Thanks

UPDATED

Found error, It doesn't work cuz guzzle 4 configuration works in different way:

```
{
    "operations": {
        "me":{
            "description": "Return solidoptics user profile details",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "uri": "users/me",
            "responseModel": "getResponse",
            "parameters": {
                "token": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "location": "header",
                    "sentAs": "Authorization",
                    "required": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "models": {
        "getResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "location": "json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now issue is not actual for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the [default request options](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L56) for the client, doing something like this:

```
$client = new Client(array(
    'defaults' => array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => '...',
         ),
    ),
));
```

And also make sure you use `$client`, not `new Client()` when calling `new GuzzleClient`!

Comment: Checked this already, it doesn't work. In my case guzzle send request to api server without Autorization header in your case it can't even execute request and instead prepared request it return NULL

Answer (score 0):

You may add new config array

```
$clientConfig['defaults']['token'] = $token;
```

and pass that config as the third argument of
`new GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient`.
Those defaults are copied into command arguments on command creation.

You could also modify the default in the Description object.

You could also possibly set defaults in the `GuzzleHttp\Client` config.